# Quarto won't render to PDF

Tags: latex, quarto, katex

I am trying to render my quarto to  pdf. This is my Yaml:

```
---
date: last-modified
toc: true
format:
  html: 
    code-fold: true
    html-math-method: katex
  pdf:
    geometry: 
      - top=30mm
      - left=30mm
  docx: default
bibliography: bibliography.bib
---
```

It does render to html and to Word. When rendering to PDF I get the message:

```
running xelatex - 1
  This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
   restricted \write18 enabled.
  entering extended mode
  
updating tlmgr

updating existing packages
finding package for tikzfill.image.sty

compilation failed- no matching packages
LaTeX Error: File `tikzfill.image.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.24 ^^M
```

Could anyone help me render to PDF? Thanks!

Comment: Try reinstalling `tinytex` (see [here](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/pdf-engine.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same issue by running `quarto install tinytex` from the terminal. See https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/pdf-basics.html#prerequisites for more info.